# Issues using Russian Doll Caching with Template Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, template-inheritance, russian-doll-caching, cache-digests

I have been using both Template Inheritance and Russian Doll Caching (using the [cache_digests gem](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests)) independently of one another in select portions of a fairly complex Rails application, with much success.

I am having difficulty using the two technologies together, in a sane way, which makes me suspect that I may be doing something wrong...

For an extremely simple example, consider an application consisting of two controllers, ThingOnes and ThingTwos. This application has one layout (`layouts/application.html.erb` ) which simply renders a header file with: `<%= render 'header' %>`.

By default, Rails will look in a bunch of locations for this partial, including the view directory for the layout ( `views/application/_header.html.erb` ) as well as any specific to the current controller ( like `views/thing_ones/_header.html.erb` or `views/thing_twos/_header.html.erb` ). This means, for caching purposes, I basically have a template dependency list ( not counting engines, or anything else ) like this:

```
[
  "application/header",
  "thing_ones/header",
  "thing_twos/header"
]
```

Now, we wrap that render call with caching, like so:

```
<% cache 'header' do %>
  <%= render 'header' %>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, running `rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies TEMPLATE=layouts/application` results in the following dependency list.

```
[
  "layouts/header"
]
```

It doesn't seem to care about template inheritance at all. Modifying the files not included in the list has the expected effect of modifying files not included in the list - the cache is not expired properly and the stale header is displayed.

This can be easily remidied by specifying the relevant template paths, like so:

```
<% cache 'header' do %>
  <%# Template Dependency: application/header %>
  <%# Template Dependency: thing_ones/header %>
  <%# Template Dependency: thing_twos/header %>
  <%= render 'header' %>
<% end %>
```

This seems like a very poor solution indeed, as it doesn't grow well, and requires a lot of frivolous decoration to cache calls in order to retain the existing template inheritance behavior.

Similarly, one can more explicitly specify the header location, like so:

```
<% cache 'header' do %>
  <%= render 'application/header' %>
<% end %>
```

This also fails to retain the existing template inheritance behavior, rendering it unsuitable for our needs.

A final option lies in moving the `cache` call into the header partials themselves. This is not only inefficient, as it leaves the `render` call out of the cache. It is also more WET (write everything twice) than DRY, which is a big turn off.

So, to get to my actual question(s)... Am I doing this correctly? This seems like a fairly major shortcoming that would be affecting a wide variety of implementations, but I can't really find a lot of discussion related to this specific issue, so I wonder if others are doing it in a way that works better. Is there a better way to do this, or at least automatically specify the entire template dependency heirarchy for partial renders?

Comment: I am starting to suspect that people just aren't persisting these caches across deploys, or something...

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is actually what you suggest yourself in the end: you have to move the `cache` method into your rendered templates.

This may seem like more code, but this is neccesarry for cache digest to work properly. Furthermore, if your partials (`_header.html.erb` in application, thing_ones and thing_twos) are different, should the cache key be different as well. This means that you should end up with something like this:

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<%= render 'header' %>

# application/_header.html.erb 
<% cache 'application_header' do %>
  ...
<% end %>

# thing_ones/_header.html.erb
<% cache 'thing_ones_header' do %>
  ...
<% end %>

# and thing_twos/_header.html.erb
<% cache 'thing_twos_header' do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Without different cache keys would these caches override each other meaning that if eg. `application/_header.html.erb` was cached first, then that would be the one that is rendered one `ThingOnes` and `ThingTwos` pages.